# How does std::forward know whether the reference is an lvalue or an rvalue?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, std, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

The utility std::forward example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/?kw=forward seems a little bit like magic.  How does it know whether the argument to the calling function is an lvalue or rvalue?  Is this determined by the compiler or at run-time?  I think there's something I don't understand here, but I don't know if I know enough to ask the question properly.  Can someone explain a little bit about what std::forward does "under the hood".

Comment: Universal reference and reference collapsing. Keyword for Google search.

Comment: Thanks, this link clarifies a lot for me: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers